# What technology stack can help my app listen and react?

Tags: java, android, http, erlang, google-cloud-messaging

Simple Question:

What pieces can I seriously explore using to allow my app to listen for an outside signal that triggers a method call/a code block?

scenario equals many apps sending a signal to a broker/queuing system that then lets these other listening apps know they have requests, so that they can execute their methods.

gcm, websockets, http PUT/POST, TCP, ?

Comment: most of the discussion in that conversation are from '09-'11, lots have evolved in this space since then.

Comment: this way we end up with question on '09-'11, question on '12-'13, question on '14-'15 and so on. I am against asking new questions because the goal of stackoverflow not only answer *your question*, but also help future visitor: so newcomer have to dig through all of the questions (yours including) and all answers and to compare whole slew of different frameworks. Moreover [stackoverflow has mechanisms to bring attention to outdated answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty). This particular question will likely have the most of the answers from question linked above and *possibly* one new.